# Page doesn't load at the right place; jquery code to do with it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a page with a `d3.js` chart that loads data from a certain year based on fragment identifiers, such as `/graph#2014` or `/graph#2013`, and so on. Upon page load, the jquery code triggers a button press which in turn renders a chart with the respective data. Here's the code to trigger all this:

```
 function yearHash() {
   if (location.hash === "") {
     $("#<%= Date.today.year %>").click();
   }
   else if (location.hash === "#2014") {
     $("#2014").click();
   }     
   else if (location.hash === "#2013") {
     $("#2013").click();
   }
   else if (location.hash === "#2012") {
     $("#2012").click();
   }
 }

 window.onhashchange = yearHash;
 window.onload = yearHash;
```

Problem is, whenever a page with a particular hash loads, it scrolls down for a bit before scrolling back up again. I'm not sure what's causing it. It's not a deal breaker but it's irritating.

Comment: Could you post the rest of the code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because when you have `#2012` it causes the browser to scroll to the first element where `id="2012` Instead of using hashes use classes. Also why not just call the drawing code from the `if` statement instead of routing it through a button click.

Comment: thanks. that fixed it. reason for doing it through the button click is such that the button will be highlighted (through a CSS switch) to indicate which year is selected.

Comment: You could still use a class.